# Angular 2 summary of ngFor values (numbers)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a situation where I need to collect all `pt` (which is in number) for each `team task` (team tasks are dynamic and from database).

TS :

```
tasks;
  getTeams(){
    this.db.list(`projects/${this.auth.userId}/${this.key}/teams`).snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(changes =>
        changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
      )
    ).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
     this.tasks = data;
    }  )}
```

HTML :

```
  <div *ngFor="let t of tasks">
        <p *ngFor="let pt of objectValues(t.tasks)">{{pt.pt}}</p>
      </div>
```

Explanation of two ngFors in photo of my firebase database :

[image]

Output :

[image]

**I want that my output for each `TEAM` would be only summary of All `pt`, how to achieve that ?**

**For example :**

**Frontas : 10pt (5 + 5)**

**Backas : 5pt (5)**

Adding console log of `console.log(data)` :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to sum the points of each task. You an use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to compute that:

### Script

```
getTeamPoints(team) {
  return Object.values(team.tasks).reduce((total, task) => total + parseInt(task.pt), 0);
}
```

Note: the above script should probably be have its variables typed.

### View

```
<div *ngFor="let team of teams">
  {{team.name}}: {{getTeamPoints(team)}} points
</div>
```

Comment: *Of each  team , because each task got only one pt value

Comment: @AndriusL. Just fixed a typo as well.

Comment: Now : Frontas: 055 points
Backas: 05 points
Tetas: 01516 points

Comment: Thats not summary I think, it only adds number near number

Comment: Didn't notice your point values were strings... this doesn't seem right. Check with my last edit (used `parseInt`).

Comment: Should be 10, 5, 31

Comment: @AndriusL. Yes because using `+` on strings concatenates. Retry now, should be OK.

Comment: Yes, changed all values to numbers and it works great !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184895/discussion-between-andrius-l-and-jeto).